# Filter a Linked List in Place in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have created the following function which filters a linked list in place
(here it removes all instances of the element k), but it could easily be modified to take a function pointer as an argument and filter on something else.

Any ideas on how to improve the code?

```
typedef struct list_integer {
    type value;
    struct list_integer *next;
} list_integer;

list_integer *removeKFromList(list_integer * l, int k)
{

    if (!l)
    return l;
    while (l && l->value == k)
    l = l->next;
    if (!l)
    return l;


    list_integer *p = l;
    list_integer *q = l->next;

  scan_in:
    if (q) {
    if (q->value != k) {
        list_integer *t = q;
        q = q->next;
        p = t;
        goto scan_in;
    } else {
        goto scan_out;
    }
    }

  scan_out:
    if (q) {
    if (q->value != k) {
        p->next = q;
        p = q;
        q = q->next;
        goto scan_in;
    } else {
        q = q->next;
        goto scan_out;
    }
    } else {
    p->next = q;
    }
    return l;

}
```

Comment: Is the indentation in your question the same as in your original code?

Answer (score 2):

## Table of contents (in no particular order)

Indent your code properly!

Don't use `goto` for something so routine. Unless you're writing a C compiler and intend to compete with GCC or Clang or you're Andrei Alexandrescu... don't use `goto` at all!

`while` loop/`for` loop can be used to accomplish what you need instead of `goto`.

Fix memory leaks. If you're in place modifying a linked list, the nodes that are removed from the list have to have their memory freed. (In general, this is the assumption going off solely your function prototype. It's possible that all the nodes are statically allocated and it's not this function's responsibility to free them but I'm assuming the more usual case.)

Use comments to explain what you're doing. Although this isn't super complicated, since it's pretty low level, comments are a good idea.

Checking for NULL: IMO it's better to do an explicit check with `== NULL` rather than `!l`. Although it is the same and is a popular choice among C programmers (I used to do it too, it made me feel smart)... it's hard to read and is not a good idea. Personally, I only use `!l` to check for bools. Others may disagree.

Better variable names. This can cut down on the amount of stuff that has to be explained in comments. Renamed `p` to `previous` and `q` to `current`. (If you really don't wanna type so much -- `prev` and `cur`).

```
typedef struct list_integer {
    type value;
    struct list_integer *next;
} list_integer;

list_integer *removeKFromList(list_integer * l, int k)
{

    if (l == NULL) return NULL; // empty list becomes empty list

    // remove the occurrences of k at the beginning
    while (l != NULL && l->value == k) { 
        list_integer* temp = l;
        l = l->next;
        free(temp); // deallocate memory
    }

    if (l == NULL) return NULL; // list of only k's becomes empty list

    // already checked in the while loop. l->value != k
    list_integer *previous = l;
    list_integer *current = l->next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->value != k) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        } else {
            while (l != NULL && l->value == k) { // remove continuous occurrences of k
                list_integer* temp = current;
                current = current->next;
                free(temp); // deallocate memory
            }
            previous->next = current;
            if(current != NULL) {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }   
        }
    }

    return l;
}
```

The version above keeps the OP's optimisation of not modifying the next pointer (i.e. `p->next`) multiple times if there are multiple continuous `k`'s.

Version without this optimisation is a bit simpler:

```
typedef struct list_integer {
    type value;
    struct list_integer *next;
} list_integer;

list_integer *removeKFromList(list_integer * l, int k)
{

    if (l == NULL) return NULL; // empty list becomes empty list

    // remove the occurrences of k at the beginning
    while (l != NULL && l->value == k) { 
        list_integer* temp = l;
        l = l->next;
        free(temp); // deallocate memory
    }

    if (l == NULL) return NULL; // list of only k's becomes empty list

    // already checked in the while loop. l->value != k
    list_integer *previous = l;
    list_integer *current = l->next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->value != k) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        } else {
            list_integer* temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            previous->next = current;
            free(temp); // deallocate memory
        }
    }

    return l;
}
```

Comment: Calling it table of contents was a joke... don't overthink it

Comment: Being more verbose or more similar to other more verbose languages is not something to strive for. Anyway, the problem is the name `l` or was it `1` or ???

Comment: As an aside, you like OP prefer the rare over the common case. The latter being that there are more nodes.

Comment: I mean... for each node, the overhead is two condition checks for a zero in a memory location that's probably hot in cache (if not already in a register)... vs a memory read+write

Comment: Yes, `l` should be in a register. But the options are letting the common case run, which only writes if needed, vs. testing for the end, and then sometimes letting the common case run. That extra-check is not needed.

Comment: too many asides.... removed the bonus, it was wrong... not worth fixing, beyond scope of question

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations on hitting on the idea that modifying pointers, even by setting them to their current value, has a cost. That cost is not necessarily insignificant either, as cache-unsharing and marking a page as dirty has immediate and follow-on costs.

Also kudos for adding a typedef-name, and making it match the tag-name.

Still there are multiple issues with your code:

1. **Proper indentation is crucial for maintainability**. Take care of it while programming to support your own understanding, and fix any warts before subjecting anyone else to it. If that's too tedious for you, it's easily automated.
2. **`goto` is rarely the solution**. It might be preferable over pushing the control-flow into flags, but there is nearly always a better structured way to go.
3. You test for an empty list twice for a quick exit. That's a optimizing the rare case to the detriment of the common case. Also, it's more code.
4. I'm hard pressed to think of a worse name than `l`. It's easily confused with other symbols. Also, its scope is too big for most single-letter names.
5. You just drop unneeded nodes. If that is actually the right thing to do, it deserves a comment to assert that was intended: `/* dropping node here */`.
   Far more likely, you just forgot to `free()` it.
6. Personally, I prefer putting the links at the beginning of the node. If double-linked, they even get their own struct.

```
typedef struct list_integer {
    struct list_integer *next;
    int value;
} list_integer;

list_integer *removeKFromList(list_integer *head, int k) {
    list_integer* r;
    list_integer** insert = &r;
    do {
        while (head && head->value == k) {
            list_integer* p = head;
            head = head->next;
            free(p);
        }
        *insert = head;
        while (*insert && (*insert)->value != k)
            insert = &(*insert)->next;
        head = *insert;
    } while (head);
    return r;
}
```